# Roll back to a previous version of lambda code without versioning enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was working on lambda function A using lambda function B code as reference
I uploaded a zip file to the lambda funcion B by mistake, this supposed to be to function A.
Theres no version control for function B. Is there a way i can roll back to the previous code before the .zip code was uploaded to function B or undo the zip upload?

Comment: Do you deploy using your own S3 bucket?

Comment: For function B i was using the code editor from aws console

Comment: If you haven't deployed the .zip fil yet to function B, you can download the original version of function B from lambda console by using `export function` button.

Comment: https://disaster-recovery.workshop.aws/en/labs/basics/lambda.html

Comment: unfortunately the deployment package of my Lambda function  is too large to enable inline code editing. So apparently is automatically deployed. ..